# Изменение размера шрифта при ресайзе

Tags: html, css, svg

Есть вот такой макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надпись " Planeta " расположина на всю ширину сайта. Как сделать так чтобы при ресайзе она пропорционально уменьшалась и всегда влазила по ширине? 
Пытался сделать через  и svg text. Пока не получилось. Возможно ли это сделать без JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

если в html head - е дабавить

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

то можно попробовать с `vw(viewport width)` и `vh(viewport height)`

```
.class {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

Comment: Выход был все таки сделать его svg картиной. Иначе не получалось.

Answer (score 1):

`vw` - единица ширины экрана
`vh` - единица высота экрана

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700|Open+Sans:400,600,700|Raleway:400,900&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #bab6b6;
  font-size: 25vw;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Planeta</div>
```